# How to get Latitude and longitude from typed address by a user in Ios 6

Tags: ios, dictionary, core-location

I am New In Ios. And I am learning MapKit and CoreLocation. I have two View Controllers in my program and In first view controller there is a text field there User can type an address. and a button. After fill address if user tap on button than it will redirect to second view controller which is map view controller. There will be two annotation. One for user's current location and Another is for user's typed address. 
So can you please tell me how to get lat, long for user's typed address and show the annotation on map view for that lat long.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is the code

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

+(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddressString:(NSString*) addressStr {

    double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
    NSString *esc_addr =  [addressStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    if (result) {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:result];
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil]) {
            [scanner scanDouble:&latitude];
            if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil]) {
                [scanner scanDouble:&longitude];
            }
        }
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = latitude;
    center.longitude = longitude;
    return center;

}
```

then call this method

```
coordinates = [self getLocationFromAddressString:@"address"];
```

Comment: 1.Need to add secure url https 2.Put api key just after address

Answer (score 3):

You can use Google Geocoding for [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests). It is as simple as getting data through HTTP and parsing it (it can return JSON KML, XML, CSV).

or

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
{
    double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
    NSString *esc_addr =  [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    if (result) {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:result];
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil]) {
            [scanner scanDouble:&latitude];
            if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil]) {
                [scanner scanDouble:&longitude];
            }
        }
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = latitude;
    center.longitude = longitude;
    return center;
}
```

Comment: hi where to call this function and how to call this funcion please replay!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
    #import core location Framework

#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

    //Current Location

    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
        coordinate = [location coordinate];
        float latitude = coordinate.latitude;
        float longitude = coordinate.longitude;
        NSLog(@"%f",latitude);
        NSLog(@"%f",longitude);


    and type location you call google webservice and pass type address and
    google api return corrdinate for type address

    http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false
```

Comment: this to fetch from the current location, not from custom address entered by user